# Question regarding K-Means Multilable problem

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, multilabel, scikit-learn

I have a dataset where for a set of features I have a single label but in my prediction I wanted to predict upto 5 labels for each test data. The labels are categorical and the number of distinct values in the training dataset is 5.

I am planning to use K-Means using this 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html

What I am not understanding is how do I need to use K-Means algorithm to predict 5 labels instead of 1.

Thanks,
Jayadeep